# Load Balancing AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ip, load-balancing

So I am completely new to load-balancing. I have an idea of what i want to do, but am not sure if it is doable with load-balancing.
I have Server A which is the main production server on AWS
and then I have Server B which is a Clone of A.
I want to create a load-balancing element to this that will come online when Clone A to create server B. The goal is to clone A and have the load transferred to server B while Server A is under maintenance.
The big thing being that I want uninterrupted service when I am doing maintenance on Server A. I then want to be able to shut down server B and the load balancing until the next time I want to do maintenance. How would I go about doing this?

Could anyone tell me if this is doable, or if there is another way I should consider doing what I am trying to do.

Thanks ahead of time guys.

Answer (score 2):

You could have a load balancer in front of server A. When you want to do maintenance add server B to the load balancer, wait for it to start accepting traffic, then remove server A from the load balancer. Do your maintenance, then add server A back to the load balancer. Once server A starts accepting traffic, remove server B from the load balancer. I think that's the closest thing to what you described in your question. The main issue would be HTTP sessions. If your server is something people log into and maintain long-running sessions then you might need to look into some sort of session replication mechanism to keep everyone from being logged out of your app when the load balancers switches them to a different server.

Another option would be to use Route53 health checks with DNS failover.

My recommendation would be to use a load balancer, and just keep two instances running and accepting traffic at all times. Do rolling updates when you need to perform maintenance.

Comment: That is a great idea. Never quite thought of using a DNS failover like that. Only question would be, would they be able to be on the same subnet?

Comment: There's no reason being on the same subnet would be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using a Load Balancer, why dont you use AWS Route53 DNS failover to achieve what you want. make sure that you choose 'Active-passive failover' record sets.

This way, when server A is not available, the traffic will be sent to server B automatically. You need to make sure that server B is up and running. If server A is ready for production again, simply shutdown server B and the traffic will go to server A again.

Reference:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/dns-failover-configuring.html

Comment: Careful with using DNS failover in place of a load balancer.  If you have continuous traffic, you'll need to go with the load balancer.  The DNS failover will only work for new domain resolutions or when the TTL has been  surpassed.  Existing traffic will still want to go to the original domain target.